# Can I change date of birth and name on US visa after entering US

Tags: usa, passport, documentation

I am an international student currently studying in the USA. My actual date of birth is 15th May, 1996. But for some personal reasons, I have been using my DOB as 15th May, 1993 and all of my identity documents have the same DOB (including my passport and US visa).

My paternal grandmother was a US citizen, and she had submitted petition for my father for family based immigration. And there, she used my real DOB (15th May, 1996). She also changed my name in the petition (My real name is Fatima Akbar Shelly, where "Fatima Akbar" is my first name and "Shelly" is my last name. All of my identity documents have this name. But in the petition, she put my name as "Fatima Akbar", where "Fatima" is my first name, and "Akbar" is my last name.) I was unaware of this, hence I kept my DOB and name as I have always been using.

Now my question is:

What should I do in the above mentioned circumstances? I already have a valid US visa with my DOB as 15th May, 1993 and name as "Fatima Akbar Shelly". I have already got my Masters, and all of my educational and social documents also include the same DOB and name. Now, can I change my name (as "Fatima Akbar") and DOB (as 15th May, 1996) in all of the documents like visa, passport and all the educational and social documents in the US? Can I immigrate to US with my father? Please kindly help me with your kind suggestions.

Comment: How do you intend changing the DOB in your passport? With a pen? Don't even think of it.

Comment: You are going to need expert advice here. You have been telling the US immigration authorities incorrect information for years. They might see this as deception and ban you for a very long time. A very skeptical person might even see this as an attempt at identity theft. This is not something you should entrust to a bunch of strangers on the internet. Get a lawyer.

Comment: +1 on getting a lawyer, this could have very serious consequences if handled improperly. Get an immigration lawyer ASAP.

Comment: Worse, you have given fake information to your own country's passport service. You not only need a US immigration lawyer, you need a lawyer in your own country to help you get your documents corrected without going to prison.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I will surely get an immigration lawyer. But, can I not get my DOB and Name changed legally? In that case, will it still be considered as providing fake information initially?

Comment: Yes, it would still be considered as having offered fake information. Changing documents now cannot change the fact that you didn't tell the truth to governmental agencies in two countries. Don't just get a lawyer — get _two_ lawyers.

Comment: If I were to declare the wrong date of birth on a passport application in my country I could be jailed for five years and fined $15,000. It is likely that similar penalties exist in your country. They certainly do in the US. This is not an innocent mistake. You need proper legal advice.

Comment: Was there any supporting evidence for the information your grandmother gave? If not . . .

Comment: What document(s) did you use to prove your DOB when you applied for your passport? And you’ve just published your personal details on the Internet, and worse, on a site dealing with visa queries...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to get advice from an Immigration lawyer

Comment: You are going to need an *extremely* good reason as to why you have been using a different date of birth on official documents, so it entirely depends on what the "personal reasons" are.  Were you under the impression at the time of the visa application that the date of birth you gave was entirely and completely the truth, or did you know at that time that it was not correct?  If the former, then you have a case to make (e.g. You discovered a birth certificate that contradicted what you had been told), but if the latter then you are in deep doo doo...

Comment: Name changes are one thing, but getting your DOB legally changed is unlikely. A famous Dutch person in his 70s tried this recently so he could pull younger women from Tinder, but his legal request was denied. Many legal thresholds are tied to age so it’s much more complicated than name or even gender.